# order by and limit condition in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

$sqlsl = "select * from newmessage where sendto='".$userid."' order by inboxid limit 10";

Pease help me,

Above table retrieve first 10 rows in my badabase in ASC order.
 My database contain 100 recordes.
 I want only first 10 recordes in DESCing order

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$sqlsl = "select * from newmessage where sendto='".$userid."' order by inboxid DESC limit 10";
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , your code works descending order of total database but i want first 10 records only in descending order not for all database.

Answer (score 3):

Please try

```
"$sqlsl = "select * from newmessage where sendto='".$userid."'
order by inboxid  DESC limit 10";
```

See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) page in the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 2):

To get the records in descending order you should add the `DESC` keyword to the `order by` clause:

```
$sqlsl = "select * from newmessage 
where sendto='".$userid."' 
order by inboxid desc 
limit 10";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

select * from (select * from newmessage where sendto='".$userid."' order by inboxid limit 10) as message_id order by message_id desc